# Need help deriving a closed-form expression for a recursive function

Tags: summation, closed-form, recursion

I am trying to find a closed form expression to allow me to solve for the nth term of the function $C(n)$, which I’ve written out below. Currently, the function for $C(n)$ is recursive, as one must solve for $C(n-1), C(n-2), C(n-3),{\cdot\cdot\cdot}$ in order to solve for $C(n)$. I have tried a bunch of different approaches, and am at the limits of my math capabilities (Bard and ChatGPT couldn’t help either). Please help me solve this! (or tell me if it’s not possible to express the following as a closed form expression.)

$$C(n) = C(0) - 2 \cdot V \cdot (1-F)\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{C(i) }{C(i) + Q \cdot V\cdot i}$$

At risk of over-explaining:

- $C(n)$ is the $n$th term of the function
- $C(0)$ is the initial condition of the function (this will be known)
- $F$ is a constant
- $V$ is a constant
- $Q$ is a constant
- $i$ is the $i$th term of the summation term, which ranges from $0$ to $n-1$

Comment: What is the context of this problem? Also could you please try formatting this with MathJax?

Comment: @Ken I made some edits. Let me know if this is correct?

Comment: Also here is the link to [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I'd bet against a closed form.

Comment: @GerryMyerson could you please elaborate?

Comment: @DavisJohnson thanks for the help. Made a couple tweaks, but may just be stylistic.

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful or not, but an equivalent version is $C(n+1)C(n)-C(n)^2+QVnC(n+1)+(2V(1-F)-QVn)C(n)=0$, obtained by looking at the expression for $C(n+1)-C(n)$.

Comment: I don't have much to say, Ken. It just doesn't look like anything I've ever seen lead to a closed form. Also, no closed form is the generic situation; recurrences with closed form solutions are few and far between.

Comment: Thanks @VarunVejalla unfortunately I need to solve for $C(n)$ with respect to $C(0)$ since the latter is known.